# Rotating view causes dynamically added checkboxes to have the same text

Tags: android, android-layout

Using a LayoutInflater, I am dynamically generating multiple TableRows, each which contains a checkbox.  Everything worked great until you rotated the display.  Each CheckBox gets the same text and checked state as the very last CheckBox created.

I found that if I assigned a unique ID to each row and to each checkbox it works correctly (each checkbox keeps its unique text and checked state).

If inflating the same layout multiple times, Do I need to assign a unique ID to every View inside the inflated layout?  That sure could be a pain if you have an involved layout that is being inflated.

Here is my code that works:

main activity

```
public class PrototypeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TableLayout tablesLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
        tablesLayout.removeAllViews();

        String[] values = new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};     

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, false);
            view.setId(i);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.tableCollectCheckBox);
            checkBox.setId(values.length+i);
            checkBox.setText(values[i]);
            tablesLayout.addView(view);
        }
        tablesLayout.invalidate();
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/tableCollectCheckBox"
            android:text="DataTable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [`checkBox.setFreezesText(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText%28boolean%29).

Comment: I tried setFreezesText.  It makes it so I do not have to reassign the text when I recreate the checkboxes, but it seems that I still must assign a unique ID to each checkbox, otherwise each checkbox gets the text and checked state of the last checkbox created.  My real question is "Do I need to assign a unique ID to every View inside an inflated layout that is inflated multiple times?"

Comment: You have to make sure that checkboxes have same id all the time, even across configuration changes. All states are saved and associated with view's id. If id is not persisted, the state will be missing or incorrect (or even corrupted) after configuration is changed.

Comment: Got it.  Each view needs to have a unique ID assigned to it, otherwise the OS incorrectly updates each view with a persisted state that could belong to another view.